# MongoDB: Can't move jumbo chunks even after changing chunk size

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm in the process of migrating from a single replica set to a sharded topology. During the initial process, I selected a chunk size that was too small and resulted in ~50% of the chunks being flagged as "jumbo". To resolve this issue, I reconfigured the chunk size and followed the instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/clear-jumbo-flag/#indivisible-chunks) to clear the jumbo flag. However, after multiple days there are no further migrations happening. But, none of the chunks have been re-flagged as "jumbo" either.

I've tried manually stopping and restarting the balancer, but that didn't seem to have any effect. I tried manually editing data in some of the jumbo chunks but that didn't have any effect either.

Running `sh.status()` shows the following...

```
balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
            No recent migrations
```

This is especially problematic because the unmoved chunks are all on a shard that I'm attempting remove from the cluster. As such, leaving them where they are isn't an option.

It looks like there may be a mechanism to manually move chunks, but this isn't really a valid option for us either as there are ~45k chunks that need to be moved.

Comment: See if this helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=257&v=0h9cRDwFX_0

Comment: Maybe the number of chunks are evenly distributed across all shards so the the threshold haven't been exceeded. The balancer only begins balancing after the distribution of chunks for a sharded collection has reached certain thresholds.